# SELECT Async with PYTHON

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make some connections to the MySQL database asynchronously, where there is a dispute and printing on the screen or result that comes first ... but I'm not able to execute ...

```
import asyncio
import aiomysql
import pymysql.cursors
from datetime import datetime

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM aluguel'
sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM filme'
sql3 = 'SELECT * FROM ator'
sql4 = 'SELECT * FROM pagamento'
sql5 = 'SELECT * FROM cliente'

def getHora():
    data = datetime.now()
    hora = data.hour
    minu = data.minute
    seg = data.second
    mseg = data.microsecond
    str_hora = str(hora) + ':' + str(minu) + ':' + str(seg) + ':' + str(mseg)
    return str_hora

async def test_example():
    conn1 = await aiomysql.connect(host='',
                                port=3306,
                                user='administrator', 
                                password='',
                                db='sakila', 
                                loop=None)
    conn2 = await aiomysql.connect(host='',
                                port=3306,
                                user='administrator', 
                                password='',
                                db='sakila', 
                                loop=None)
    conn3 = await aiomysql.connect(host='',
                                port=3306,
                                user='administrator', 
                                password='',
                                db='sakila', 
                                loop=None)
    conn4 = await aiomysql.connect(host='',
                                port=3306,
                                user='administrator', 
                                password='',
                                db='sakila', 
                                loop=None)
    conn5 = await aiomysql.connect(host='',
                                port=3306,
                                user='administrator', 
                                password='',
                                db='sakila', 
                                loop=None)
    try:                             
        print(getHora())
        cur1 = await conn1.cursor()
        cur2 = await conn2.cursor()
        cur3 = await conn3.cursor()
        cur4 = await conn4.cursor()
        cur5 = await conn5.cursor()

        print('req 1',await cur1.execute(sql1))
        print('req 2',await cur2.execute(sql2))
        print('req 3',await cur3.execute(sql3))
        print('req 4',await cur4.execute(sql4))
        print('req 5',await cur5.execute(sql5))

        await cur1.close()
        await cur2.close()
        await cur3.close()
        await cur4.close()
        await cur5.close()

    finally:
        conn1.close()
        conn2.close()
        conn3.close()
        conn4.close()
        conn5.close()
        print(getHora())

loop.run_until_complete(test_example())
```

this was the last code I got, trying to make five connections to the bank and 5 queries but the code above always comes first .. does anyone have any idea how I can make them compete?

Comment: Hi, Thanks man, you answer resolved my problem !! Sorry my long time answer you!!
Thanks

Comment: No problem! Please note that on StackOverflow you're supposed to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/627709) an answer once the question is fully answered. This gives the volunteer who wrote the answer a token reputation reward, and provides future visitors information that the issue is in fact resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compete, you need to run the coroutines in parallel using `asyncio.create_task` or `asyncio.gather`:

```
async def test(reqid, sql):
    conn = await aiomysql.connect(
        host='', port=3306, user='administrator', password='', db='sakila')
    try:                             
        print(getHora())
        cur = await conn.cursor()
        print(reqid, await cur.execute(sql))
        await cur.close()
    finally:
        conn.close()
        print(getHora())

async def compete():
    await asyncio.gather(
        test('req 1', sql1),
        test('req 2', sql2),
        test('req 3', sql3),
        test('req 4', sql4),
        test('req 5', sql5),
    )

asyncio.run(compete())
```